# Creating image-gallery in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET MVC app for uploading and getting images from the client, but it is not working as well.

Something is wrong with the `HttpGet` method.

Here is my project:

https://github.com/SashaMaksyutenko/imageGalleryApp_aspNet

```
function LoadSlider(val) {
    $.ajax
        ({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api/Gallery/' + val,
        dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $(".swiper-wrapper").html("");
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $(".swiper-wrapper").append("<div class='swiper-slide'><img width='100%' height='350px' src='" + value.image_Path + "' />" + value.image_Caption + "</div>");
            });
                var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
                    pagination: {
                        el: '.swiper-pagination',
                        type: 'progressbar',
                    },
                    navigation: {
                        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
                        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
                    },
                });
        }
    });
}
```

maybe here is the problem - its might be a slider in which we getting images from folders, but I'm not sure

this method from custom.js file

Comment: Post the relevant pieces of code directly here, in the question, as properly formatted code snippets

Comment: I don't know which file is the problem.
It seems to me that in the custom.js file in the loadSlider() method

Answer (score 0):

there few issues,
firstly the drop down loadGalleries function doesn't seam to be properly bound, the db is saving the image path with back slashes but you need forward slashes , this is because of how your mapping the file path server side

```cs
  string dbImageGalleryPath = Path.Combine($"{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}Uploads{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}Gallery{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}", id.ToString());
```

and it wasn't mapping the json property's i.e. galleryId and title, to fix all this you can do something like this:

```js
value.image_Path = value.image_Path.replace(/\\/g, '/');
 $('.swiper-wrapper').append("<div class='swiper-slide'><img width='100%' height='350px' src='" + value.image_Path + "' />" + value.image_Caption + "</div>");
```

that will fix the loadSlider witch was failing because it wasn't receiving an id value from the drop down

the next issue you have is your saving the images to  \image_gallery\Uploads\

but they need to be in the www folder \wwwroot\Uploads\Gallery\ otherwise they wont be accessible

I hope this helps

Comment: Can you tell me please step by step what and where should I change?

Comment: sure , sorry if i didn't explain it properly, change the custom.js, and in the function 

```function loadSlider(val) {```

use the javascript I posted above, 

```eg
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
   value.image_Path = value.image_Path.replace(/\\/g, '/');
   $('.swiper-wrapper').append("<div class='swiper-slide'><img width='100%' height='350px' src='.." + value.image_Path + "' />" + value.image_Caption + "</div>");
});
```

that should fix it for you

Comment: And that’s all what I have to change ?

Comment: from my testing of your code yes, that seamed to work for me. You will find though that you see an empty image icon and not the actual the image but that's because the images are been saved to the wrong location i.e. not in \wwwroot\Uploads\Gallery\ folder if you change our code to save them there the path for the image src will be correct and it will then display

Comment: It’s still not working

Comment: i put the fix here for you: https://github.com/PTAHume/imageGalleryApp_aspNet, i fixed it so the images save to the www folder so also should display now

Comment: thank you. Can you help me with some other project?

Comment: possibly depends what it is and what help you need ?

Comment: I can see the pictures on slider but i can't delete them

Comment: if I upload image and press on Submit after this i can't to upload files for the second time

Comment: this is another project where web-project in solution doesn't working https://github.com/SashaMaksyutenko/ShopOnline

Comment: so i fixed the delete, the issue was the url when you set ```window.location.href``` I also fix a few other bugs, the edit doesn't look like it wired up in the preview or upload or in the main Options select item but I guess you haven't gotten that far yet i also tidied up the JS to remove vars, the get git hub for latest changes

Comment: also may have accidentally uploaded a picture of myself haha and committed it when I did the push to GH please disregard that, I think I removed it afterwards my bad lol !?

Comment: I meant if I want to delete gallery in slider and press on the button Yes in the modal window - the image is deleting. But now it is not working .

Comment: the delete in the gallery works for me, have you checked the latest changes i pushed ?

Comment: seems like there deleted two images from <div> only. I didn't saw other changes

Comment: so you dont see these changes: https://github.com/PTAHume/imageGalleryApp_aspNet/commit/16bb05bf4c80467281641b0aed272f90e3570e06 ? might be with doing a ms teams meeting, or webex or skype or zoom

Comment: i'll watch it later. Thank you for help.

Comment: ok I was also able to fix your blazer protect so that it works: https://github.com/PTAHume/ShopOnline

Comment: I saw one photo on GiitHub. Very nice photo. Is it really you?

Comment: SMEG! yer please pretend you didn't see that lol ...really didn't mean to commit that at the time I was just testing and only had a few photos of myself =/ was meant to remove it before i committed the changes but totally forgot

Comment: it's interesting to have chat with you. Can we talk another way - gmail or something else? And thank you for helping me.

Comment: thats ok , do you have ms teams, or webex or skype or zoom, slack or discord ?

Comment: I have ms teams. What about Gmail?

Comment: patricktahume@gmail.com or https://teams.live.com/meet/9416244292826